# How to use `numpy.savez` in a loop for save more than one array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

From a loop I'm getting an array. I want to save this arrays in a `tempfile`.
The problem is that `np.savez` only saves the last array from the loop. I think I understand why this happens, but dont know how to do it better.

To solve my problem I had the idea to open the tempfile in `mode=a+b` with the goal to append the new arrays from the loop. But this doesn't work.

My code so far:

```
tmp = TemporaryFile(mode="a+b")    
for i in range(10):
  array = getarray[i]  #demo purpose
  np.savez(tmp,array)
tmp.seek(0)
```

Then using the tempfile to read the arrays:

```
tmp_read = np.load(tmp)
print tmp_read.files
[OUTPUT]: ['arr_0']
```

But I want 10 arrays in the tempfile. Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: If the arrays are too large to be allocated in memory altogether, and you want to stick to a for loop, use one file per each array. I don't think you can use `.npz` files in append mode.

Comment: A `.npz` is a standard zip archive.  That means that `.npy` files can be added or removed with almost any archiving tool (from with in Python or shell or window).  It's easy to play with.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `*args` arguments to save many arrays in only one temp file.

```
np.savez(tmp, *getarray[:10])
```

or:

```
np.savez(tmp, *[getarray[0], getarray[1], getarray[8]])
```

Comment: Couldn't the syntax be shorten to just `*getarray[:10]`? The list comprehension is a bit unnecessary if `getarray` is already a list.

Comment: @imaluengo you are right, the example would be better showing that many arrays could be saved, e.g. by doing `[getarray[0], getarray[2], getarray[3]]`

Comment: Yep! I see the point, I just thought was worth mentioning that `*myarraylist` could be used to shorten the syntax in case that list is already created :)

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro but this does not answer the question of how to use this in a for-loop.  If saving to `.npz` overwrites everything but the purpose of the loop is to 'append' the next array, this won't work.

Comment: @mLstudent33 do you want to open the same `.npz` file, read it, append a new array and write it all again?

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro, yes, I'm guessing I have to do some sort of seek operation to the end of the `.npz` file but am not sure.  I got it working now where I just append all my numpy arrays to a list then another list (so list of lists) and then do one `np.savez()` at the end of my program.  I have not checked the contents yet but I'm guessing it works for a list of lists of numpy arrays?

Comment: @mLstudent33 it does work for list of lists, you will perhaps need to use `allow_pickle=True`. There are many ways to come up with a good approach, keeping in mind that one should avoid re-reading or re-writing data

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro, I just tried `np.load()` and it told me just that, `ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False`.  Also, my arrays should be RBG images but they seem to have picked up an extra dimension.  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> `(1, 586, 506, 3) 889548
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1, 587, 505, 3) 889305
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1, 576, 502, 3) 867456`

Comment: it worked with `thumbs = np.load('20-7of10thumbs.npz', allow_pickle=True)` and looping through each to `np.reshape`:  `for i in range(len(thumbs)):
    img = thumbs["arr_{}".format(i)]
    _, h, w, ch = img.shape
    img = np.reshape(img, (h,w,ch))
    print(type(img), img.shape, img.size)
    cv2.imshow("arr_{}".format(i), img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)`

Answer (score 11):

It is also possible to use custom keys by using `**` operator.

```
import numpy as np

a1 = [1,2,3]
a2 = [10,20,30]

savez_dict = dict()

for i in ['a1', 'a2']:
    savez_dict['key_'+i] = i 

np.savez("t.npz", **savez_dict)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for my English in advance.

Because the function savez opens the file, writes all variables, then close the file, data are over-written when it called.

savez is simple. you can find the code at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py

how about implementing "your_own_savez", then use the following code.

```
tmp = TemporaryFile()
f = my_savez(tmp)    
for i in range(10):
    array = getarray[i]  #demo purpose
    f.savez(array)
f.close()

tmp.seek(0)
tmp_read = np.load(tmp)
print tmp_read.files
```

Here is my quick and dirty code.

```
import numpy as np
import tempfile

class my_savez(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        # Import is postponed to here since zipfile depends on gzip, an optional
        # component of the so-called standard library.
        import zipfile
        # Import deferred for startup time improvement
        import tempfile
        import os

        if isinstance(file, basestring):
            if not file.endswith('.npz'):
                file = file + '.npz'

        compression = zipfile.ZIP_STORED

        zip = self.zipfile_factory(file, mode="w", compression=compression)

        # Stage arrays in a temporary file on disk, before writing to zip.
        fd, tmpfile = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='-numpy.npy')
        os.close(fd)

        self.tmpfile = tmpfile
        self.zip = zip
        self.i = 0

    def zipfile_factory(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import zipfile
        import sys
        if sys.version_info >= (2, 5):
            kwargs['allowZip64'] = True
        return zipfile.ZipFile(*args, **kwargs)

    def savez(self, *args, **kwds):
        import os
        import numpy.lib.format as format

        namedict = kwds
        for val in args:
            key = 'arr_%d' % self.i
            if key in namedict.keys():
                raise ValueError("Cannot use un-named variables and keyword %s" % key)
            namedict[key] = val
            self.i += 1

        try:
            for key, val in namedict.iteritems():
                fname = key + '.npy'
                fid = open(self.tmpfile, 'wb')
                try:
                    format.write_array(fid, np.asanyarray(val))
                    fid.close()
                    fid = None
                    self.zip.write(self.tmpfile, arcname=fname)
                finally:
                    if fid:
                        fid.close()
        finally:
            os.remove(self.tmpfile)

    def close(self):
        self.zip.close()

tmp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
f = my_savez(tmp)
for i in range(10):
  array = np.zeros(10)
  f.savez(array)
f.close()

tmp.seek(0)

tmp_read = np.load(tmp)
print tmp_read.files
for k, v in tmp_read.iteritems():
     print k, v
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not an experienced programmer, but this is the way I did it (just in case it may help someone in the future). In addition, it is the first time that I am posting here, so I apologize if I am not following some kind of standard ;)

Creating the npz file:

```
import numpy as np

tmp = file("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\temp_npz.npz",'wb')

# some variables
a= [23,4,67,7]
b= ['w','ww','wwww']
c= np.ones((2,6))

# a lit containing the name of your variables
var_list=['a','b','c']

# save the npz file with the variables you selected
str_exec_save = "np.savez(tmp,"    
for i in range(len(var_list)):    
    str_exec_save += "%s = %s," % (var_list[i],var_list[i])
str_exec_save += ")"
exec(str_exec_save)

tmp.close
```

Loading the variables with their original names:

```
import numpy as np
import tempfile

tmp = open("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\temp_npz.npz",'rb')

# loading of the saved variables
var_load = np.load(tmp)

# getting the name of the variables
files = var_load.files

# loading then with their original names
for i in range(len(files)):
    exec("%s = var_load['%s']" % (files[i],files[i]) )
```

The only difference is that the variables will become numpy variables.