# How to save arrays using savez

Tags: python, numpy

I have come across different examples. But I couldn't understand them. Here are my lists:
In the first list I am saving weights and in the second corresponding keys are 
 stored.

```
        self.weight_list=[]
        self.keys=[]
```

for example :

```
# conv1_1
    with tf.name_scope('conv1_1') as scope:
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 3, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                 stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
        biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                             trainable=True, name='biases')
        out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
        self.conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
        self.parameters += [kernel, biases]
    self.keys.append('conv1_1')
    self.weight_list.append(self.parameters)
```

I don't how to save these arrays in npz format.

I tried implementing this example [How to use `numpy.savez` in a loop for save more than one array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712292/how-to-use-numpy-savez-in-a-loop-for-save-more-than-one-array)
 and it is giving this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 355, in <module>
    vgg = vgg16(imgs1,imgs2, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)
  File "f.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.SaveWeights()
  File "f.py", line 344, in SaveWeights
    exec(str_exec_save)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'conv1_1' is not defined
```

Here is how I implemented it

```
def SaveWeights(self):

    tmp = file("vgg16_predict.npz",'wb')




        # save the npz file with the variables you selected
    str_exec_save = "np.savez(tmp,"    
    for i in range(len(self.keys)):    
         str_exec_save += "%s = %s," % (self.keys[i],self.keys[i])
         str_exec_save += ")"
         exec(str_exec_save)

    tmp.close
```

Comment: Could you show what you've tried, and describe how it's failing?

Comment: I have seen this example :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712292/how-to-use-numpy-savez-in-a-loop-for-save-more-than-one-array

Comment: What i don't understand is how do I link keys and weights lists..I hope my question is clear

Comment: are you implementing neural network from scratch? then what framework are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably works:

```
numpy.savez(**dict(zip(self.keys, self.weight_list)))
```

With the double asterisk `**` to unpack a dict to keyword arguments. This is conceptually the same as `numpy.savez(conv1_1=self.parameters, conv1_2=..., ...)`.

Comment: tried implementing your solution. Got this error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 350, in <module>
    vgg = vgg16(imgs1,imgs2, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)
  File "f.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.SaveWeights()
  File "f.py", line 339, in SaveWeights
    np.savez(**dict(zip(self.keys, self.weight_list)))
TypeError: savez() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: I added the argument self as well and it is working fine now. Thanks